# Adding foreign keys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I want to add foreign keys in one table based on primary key referencing to multiple columns in the parent table,but getting null values added in the foreign key table.

The first table was created using this query from a table gene pair which only had gene1 and gene2 columns given below:

```
 create table id_genepair(  
    id int not null auto_increment, 
    constraint id_pk primary key(id,geneid1,geneid2)
 );
 select * from gene pair;
```

Now,This is my parent table created using the above query.

```
id      gene1  gene2

1       819    2798
2       5535   2798
3       5478   2798
```

This is my second table(genepair_drugid) where I want to add foreign keys,wherever the genepair(gene1,gene2) from the above table is present

```
    gene1   geneid1   drugid1      gene1    geneid2  drugid2

    CAMLG   819        DB00091      GNRHR   2798    DB00007
    PPP3R2  5535       DB00091      GNRHR   2798    DB00007
    PPIA    5478       DB00091      GNRHR   2798    DB00007
    CAMLG   819        DB00087      GNRHR   2798    DB00051
```

I am using this query:

```
   create table id_genepair_drugid(
      Drugpair_id int not null auto_increment ,
      id_pk int not null,
      primary key (Drugpair_id),
      foreign key (id_pk) References id_genepair(id_pk)
   );
  select * from genepair_drugid;
```

Basically, I want to have Drugpair_id as unique primary key for this table, and id_pk to be the foreign key.

```
Drugpair_id  id_pk gene1   geneid1   drugid1      gene1    geneid2  drugid2

   1       0       CAMLG    819    DB00091      GNRHR   2798    DB00007
   2       0       PPP3R2   5535    DB00091     GNRHR   2798    DB00007
   3       0       PPIA    5478    DB00091      GNRHR   2798    DB00007
   4       0       CAMLG   819       DB00087      GNRHR   2798    DB00051
```

So, the issue is my id_pk column which is a foreign key should have 1,2,3,1 as the values from the id_genepair table ,I created above,but I am getting all O's.

Thanks,

Comment: while inserting data to table what did you inserted into `id_pk` column?

Comment: zeroes are getting inserted into that column, but it should have 1,2,3,1 as id 1 is repeated two times if you see.

Comment: FK values are not filled by the database.

Comment: Then whats the way of filling these values?

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do. It is hard to tell your goal by looking at your DDL.

Comment: My first table has unique id's due to the unique pairing of genes.I want my second table to have those id's as a foreign key wherever those gene pair occurs.The first 3 rows in second table should have values in the second column to be 1,2 and 3 respectively.The 4th row should have value 1 because the gene pair is repeated from the first row in the primary/first/parent table.I hope it makes more sense now.